# how do i make list of list python

Tags: python, list, append, tuples

Extracting data from Excel sheet

```
for value in quoted.findall(str(row[2])):
    i.append(value.replace('"', '').strip())
print i
```

Then i get a set of lists as below

```
['M', 'N', 'O']
['P', 'Q', 'R']
['S', 'T', 'U']
['W', 'X', 'Y']
```

how do i make this set of list in another list, i am expecting output as

```
[ ['M', 'N', 'O'], ['P', 'Q', 'R'], ['S', 'T', 'U'], ['W', 'X', 'Y'] ]
```

if i want to access this list, i simply use `listOfList[2]` and i should get

```
['S', 'T', 'U']
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing. just append the entire list to another list:

```
j=[];
for row in ... :
    i = []
    for value in quoted.findall(str(row[2])):
        i.append(value.replace('"', '').strip())

    j.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

The same as in Nirk's answer but using list comprehensions:

```
j = [[value.replace('"', '').strip() for value in quoted.findall(str(row[2]))] for row in ...]
```